# How to save S3 object to a file using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

I'm trying to do a "hello world" with new [boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3) client for AWS.

The use-case I have is fairly simple: get object from S3 and save it to the file.

In boto 2.X I would do it like this:

```
import boto
key = boto.connect_s3().get_bucket('foo').get_key('foo')
key.get_contents_to_filename('/tmp/foo')
```

In boto 3 . I can't find a clean way to do the same thing, so I'm manually iterating over the "Streaming" object:

```
import boto3
key = boto3.resource('s3').Object('fooo', 'docker/my-image.tar.gz').get()
with open('/tmp/my-image.tar.gz', 'w') as f:
    chunk = key['Body'].read(1024*8)
    while chunk:
        f.write(chunk)
        chunk = key['Body'].read(1024*8)
```

or

```
import boto3
key = boto3.resource('s3').Object('fooo', 'docker/my-image.tar.gz').get()
with open('/tmp/my-image.tar.gz', 'w') as f:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: key['Body'].read(4096), b''):
        f.write(chunk)
```

And it works fine. I was wondering is there any "native" boto3 function that will do the same task?

Answer (score 300, accepted):

There is a customization that went into Boto3 recently which helps with this (among other things). It is currently exposed on the low-level S3 client, and can be used like this:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
open('hello.txt').write('Hello, world!')

# Upload the file to S3
s3_client.upload_file('hello.txt', 'MyBucket', 'hello-remote.txt')

# Download the file from S3
s3_client.download_file('MyBucket', 'hello-remote.txt', 'hello2.txt')
print(open('hello2.txt').read())
```

These functions will automatically handle reading/writing files as well as doing multipart uploads in parallel for large files.

Note that `s3_client.download_file` won't create a directory. It can be created as `pathlib.Path('/path/to/file.txt').parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)`.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks for your reply. Can you reply the answer if i want to upload file using multipart upload in boto3.

Comment: @RahulKumarPatle the `upload_file` method will automatically use multipart uploads for large files.

Comment: @Daniel - Regarding multipart_upload, I created a [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34303775/complete-a-multipart-upload-with-boto3). The `upload_file` method doesn't seem to automatically use multipart upload for file sizes that exceed the `multipart_threshold` configuration; at least, I haven't been able to get it to work that way. I'd love to be wrong! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you pass you credentials using this approach?

Comment: @JHowIX you can either configure the credentials globally (e.g. see http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html#configuration) or you can pass them when creating the client. See http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.client for more info on available options!

Comment: it's beyond my understanding how `.upload_file` and `.download_file` arguments order is not the same.

Comment: @VladNikiporoff "Upload from source to destination" "Download from source to destination"

Comment: Hey @Daniel, a follow up question to the statement `s3_client.download_file won't create a directory`. What happens when this is called using API Gateway + Lambda? Where will it store the file, if I enter the `Filename` parameter as `/tmp/filename`?

Answer (score 86):

boto3 now has a nicer interface than the client:

```
resource = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = resource.Bucket('MyBucket')
my_bucket.download_file(key, local_filename)
```

This by itself isn't tremendously better than the `client` in the accepted answer (although the docs say that it does a better job retrying uploads and downloads on failure) but considering that resources are generally more ergonomic (for example, the s3 [bucket](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucket) and [object](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object) resources are nicer than the client methods) this does allow you to stay at the resource layer without having to drop down.

[`Resources`](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/core/resources.html) generally can be created in the same way as clients, and they take all or most of the same arguments and just forward them to their internal clients.

Comment: Great example, and to add in since the original question asks about saving an object, the relevant method here is `my_bucket.upload_file()` (or `my_bucket.upload_fileobj()` if you have a BytesIO object).

Comment: Exactly where do the docs say that `resource` does a better job at retrying? I couldn't find any such indication.

Answer (score 48):

For those of you who would like to simulate the `set_contents_from_string` like boto2 methods, you can try

```
import boto3
from cStringIO import StringIO

s3c = boto3.client('s3')
contents = 'My string to save to S3 object'
target_bucket = 'hello-world.by.vor'
target_file = 'data/hello.txt'
fake_handle = StringIO(contents)

# notice if you do fake_handle.read() it reads like a file handle
s3c.put_object(Bucket=target_bucket, Key=target_file, Body=fake_handle.read())
```

---

**For Python3:**

In python3 both [StringIO and cStringIO are gone](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html). Use the `StringIO` import like:

```
from io import StringIO
```

To support both version:

```
try:
   from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
   from io import StringIO
```

Comment: That's the answer. Here's the question: "How do you save a string to an S3 object using boto3?"

Comment: for python3 I had to use 
import io; fake_handl e= io.StringIO(contents)

Answer (score 25):

```
# Preface: File is json with contents: {'name': 'Android', 'status': 'ERROR'}

import boto3
import io

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

obj = s3.Object('my-bucket', 'key-to-file.json')
data = io.BytesIO()
obj.download_fileobj(data)

# object is now a bytes string, Converting it to a dict:
new_dict = json.loads(data.getvalue().decode("utf-8"))

print(new_dict['status']) 
# Should print "Error"
```

Comment: Never put your AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID or your AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY in your code. These should be defined with the awscli `aws configure` command and they will be found automatically by `botocore`.

Answer (score 5):

**Note: I'm assuming you have configured authentication separately. Below code is to download the single object from the S3 bucket.**

```
import boto3

#initiate s3 client 
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

#Download object to the file    
s3.Bucket('mybucket').download_file('hello.txt', '/tmp/hello.txt')
```

Comment: This code will not download from inside and s3 folder, is there a way to do it using this way?

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to download a version of a file, you need to use `get_object`.

```
import boto3

bucket = 'bucketName'
prefix = 'path/to/file/'
filename = 'fileName.ext'

s3c = boto3.client('s3')
s3r = boto3.resource('s3')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for version in s3r.Bucket(bucket).object_versions.filter(Prefix=prefix + filename):
        file = version.get()
        version_id = file.get('VersionId')
        obj = s3c.get_object(
            Bucket=bucket,
            Key=prefix + filename,
            VersionId=version_id,
        )
        with open(f"{filename}.{version_id}", 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in obj['Body'].iter_chunks(chunk_size=4096):
                f.write(chunk)
```

Ref: https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html

Answer (score 4):

When you want to read a file with a different configuration than the default one, feel free to use either [`mpu.aws.s3_download(s3path, destination)`](https://github.com/MartinThoma/mpu) directly or the copy-pasted code:

```
def s3_download(source, destination,
                exists_strategy='raise',
                profile_name=None):
    """
    Copy a file from an S3 source to a local destination.

    Parameters
    ----------
    source : str
        Path starting with s3://, e.g. 's3://bucket-name/key/foo.bar'
    destination : str
    exists_strategy : {'raise', 'replace', 'abort'}
        What is done when the destination already exists?
    profile_name : str, optional
        AWS profile

    Raises
    ------
    botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError
        Botocore is not able to find your credentials. Either specify
        profile_name or add the environment variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SESSION_TOKEN.
        See https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html
    """
    exists_strategies = ['raise', 'replace', 'abort']
    if exists_strategy not in exists_strategies:
        raise ValueError('exists_strategy \'{}\' is not in {}'
                         .format(exists_strategy, exists_strategies))
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=profile_name)
    s3 = session.resource('s3')
    bucket_name, key = _s3_path_split(source)
    if os.path.isfile(destination):
        if exists_strategy is 'raise':
            raise RuntimeError('File \'{}\' already exists.'
                               .format(destination))
        elif exists_strategy is 'abort':
            return
    s3.Bucket(bucket_name).download_file(key, destination)

from collections import namedtuple

S3Path = namedtuple("S3Path", ["bucket_name", "key"])


def _s3_path_split(s3_path):
    """
    Split an S3 path into bucket and key.

    Parameters
    ----------
    s3_path : str

    Returns
    -------
    splitted : (str, str)
        (bucket, key)

    Examples
    --------
    >>> _s3_path_split('s3://my-bucket/foo/bar.jpg')
    S3Path(bucket_name='my-bucket', key='foo/bar.jpg')
    """
    if not s3_path.startswith("s3://"):
        raise ValueError(
            "s3_path is expected to start with 's3://', " "but was {}"
            .format(s3_path)
        )
    bucket_key = s3_path[len("s3://"):]
    bucket_name, key = bucket_key.split("/", 1)
    return S3Path(bucket_name, key)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. `NameError: name '_s3_path_split' is not defined`

Comment: @DaveLiu Thank you for the hint; I've adjusted the code. The package should have worked before, though.