# Python Boto3 AWS Multipart Upload Syntax

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I am successfully authenticating with AWS and using the 'put_object' method on the Bucket object to upload a file. Now I want to use the multipart API to accomplish this for large files. I found the accepted answer in this question:
[How to save S3 object to a file using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378763/how-to-save-s3-object-to-a-file-using-boto3)

But when trying to implement I am getting "unknown method" errors. What am I doing wrong? My code is below. Thanks!

```
## Get an AWS Session
self.awsSession = Session(aws_access_key_id=accessKey,
aws_secret_access_key=secretKey,
aws_session_token=session_token,
region_name=region_type)  

 ...          

# Upload the file to S3
s3 = self.awsSession.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket('prodbucket').put_object(Key=fileToUpload, Body=data) # WORKS
#s3.Bucket('prodbucket').upload_file(dataFileName, 'prodbucket', fileToUpload) # DOESNT WORK
#s3.upload_file(dataFileName, 'prodbucket', fileToUpload) # DOESNT WORK
```

Comment: Have you seen the new, high-level interface for file upload in boto3?  See https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html#module-boto3.s3.transfer for details but it makes it much easier to do multipart uploads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upload_file method has not been ported over to the bucket resource yet.  For now you'll need to use the client object directly to do this:

```
client = self.awsSession.client('s3')
client.upload_file(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Libcloud S3 wrapper](http://libcloud.readthedocs.org/en/latest/storage/drivers/s3.html) transparently handles all the splitting and uploading of the parts for you.

Use upload_object_via_stream method to do so:

```
from libcloud.storage.types import Provider
from libcloud.storage.providers import get_driver

# Path to a very large file you want to upload
FILE_PATH = '/home/user/myfile.tar.gz'

cls = get_driver(Provider.S3)
driver = cls('api key', 'api secret key')

container = driver.get_container(container_name='my-backups-12345')

# This method blocks until all the parts have been uploaded.
extra = {'content_type': 'application/octet-stream'}

with open(FILE_PATH, 'rb') as iterator:
    obj = driver.upload_object_via_stream(iterator=iterator,
                                          container=container,
                                          object_name='backup.tar.gz',
                                          extra=extra)
```

For official documentation on S3 Multipart feature, refer to [AWS Official Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-multipart-upload/).