# Running AWS CLI through Python returns a "sh: 1: aws: not found" error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, s3cmd

I am trying to copy a file into an S3 bucket, using Python, like so:

```
cmd = 'aws s3 %s %s' % (filename, bucketname)
os.system(cmd)
```

It gives me a `sh: 1: aws: not found` error.

However, using `s3cmd` works just fine.

Why would `s3cmd` work, but not `aws`?

Also, I did `which aws` and it returned: `/home/username/anaconda/bin/aws`.

`which s3cmd` returns: `/home/username/anaconda/bin/s3cmd`.

Why does one work, but not the other, despite having the same root?

Comment: Try using the full path.

Comment: @jonnybazookatone: I'll try that. But why would one work, and not the other? My bashrc has the right path too..

Comment: I'm not sure, it shouldn't matter. But it'll be interesting if that doesn't work, as it'll suggest some other underlying problem that isn't path related.

Comment: @jonnybazookatone: Will do. I'll update this question when I try it out and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: @jonnybazookatone: It does work, but I'm still confused as to why it works!

Comment: @jonnybazookatone: Can you write this as an answer so that I can mark it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way to troubleshoot the issue is to try the full path on the OS call to see if it is a PATH problem:

```
cmd = '/path/to/aws s3 %s %s' % (filename, bucketname)
os.system(cmd)
```

There could be a few reasons why this is a problem, most likely related to the PATH variable (at first guess). However, it might be better to steer away from os.system as noted in the docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) and use some alternative methods.

Using subprocess:

```
cmd = ['/path/to/aws', 's3', filename, bucketname]
subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

Or just use the python AWS client boto3 package. There are many ways, but one quick example from this SO question ([How to save S3 object to a file using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378763/how-to-save-s3-object-to-a-file-using-boto3)):

```
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client.upload_file(filename, bucketname, filename)
```

That one is not testable with moto, which can be annoying. Instead if you want to test, you can do something like this:

```
import boto3
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    binary = f.read()

s3_resource.Bucket(bucketname).put_object(
    Key=filename,
    Body=binary
)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because the AWSCLI is not installed in your system. I had also the same problem and I tried installing it with the pip package manager using `pip install --user awscli` but it didn't work. So I installed it directly in the system as follows:

```
curl "https://d1vvhvl2y92vvt.cloudfront.net/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
```

**And the error was solved.**

Answer (score 0):

Install directly from the zip: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html#cliv2-linux-install

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
```