# Straightforward way to save the contents of an S3 key to a string in boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

So when I issue a get() what I have is a dict and the 'Body' member of the dict is a "StreamingBody' type and per [How to save S3 object to a file using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378763/how-to-save-s3-object-to-a-file-using-boto3), I see how I could read from this stream in chunks, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do this, a la boto.

Comment: Update:  I have done

` 
response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bn,Key=obj['Key'])
contents = response['Body'].read()
`

which seems to work.

Answer (score 21):

Update:  I have done

```
response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bn,Key=obj['Key'])
contents = response['Body'].read()
```

which seems to work.

Comment: assuming "Body" contains string data, ou can use object.get()["Body"].read() to convert to a Python string