# How to choose an AWS profile when using boto3 to connect to CloudFront

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudfront

I am using the Boto 3 python library, and want to connect to AWS CloudFront.
I need to specify the correct AWS Profile (AWS Credentials), but looking at the official documentation, I see no way to specify it.

I am initializing the client using the code:
`client = boto3.client('cloudfront')`

However, this results in it using the default profile to connect.
I couldn't find a method where I can specify which profile to use.

Comment: See also: [read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36205481/562769) and [download](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51993119/562769) a file from AWS S3 with profiles

Comment: have you tried using the keys into the code? (also you can use env var to hide it from the code) `client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id = '<access-key>', aws_secret_access_key = '<secret-key>')`

Answer (score 458, accepted):

I think the docs aren't wonderful at exposing how to do this. It has been a supported feature for some time, however, and there are some details in this [pull request](https://github.com/boto/boto3/pull/69).

So there are three different ways to do this:

Option A) Create a new session with the profile

```
    dev = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='dev')
```

Option B) Change the profile of the default session in code

```
    boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='dev')
```

Option C) Change the profile of the default session with an environment variable

```
    $ AWS_PROFILE=dev ipython
    >>> import boto3
    >>> s3dev = boto3.resource('s3')
```

Comment: Shouldn't the env variable be AWS_PROFILE?

Comment: Thanks for that! didn't seem to find that information anywhere so far.  It seems I only needed step 2 to make this work though.  What did step 1 do? (since the dev variable isn't used or passed into anything else?)

Comment: Those are options, not steps. In the first option you create a new session to use rather than the default session. So to create a client with that session you would do something like `dev.client('s3')` instead of `boto3.client('s3')`

Comment: off topic, `ipython` was also useful for me.

Comment: Get the profile list using `boto3.session.Session().available_profiles` - it is a list. Then use the one you want @jordan-phillips.

Comment: This works when you have two separate AWS accounts you need to connect to as well.  In `~/.aws/credentials` underneath the `[default]` entry, create a new entry named `['dev']` with the separate access keys.  End results will be two sets of access keys, one file.  Then specify the session in python like above:  `dev = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='dev')`

Comment: What is the difference between `boto3.Session` and `boto3.session.Session`?
Both methods work for me.

Answer (score 103):

[This section](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html#shared-credentials-file) of the boto3 documentation is helpful.

Here's what worked for me:

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='dev')
client = session.client('cloudfront')
```

Comment: I really thought this was going to work for me in my work with Secrets Manager. But Secrets Manager + KMS = nope.

Answer (score 75):

Do this to use a profile with name 'dev':

```
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='dev')
s3 = session.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

Answer (score 10):

1- To use Session `boto3.session.Session`:

```
import boto3
aws_session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='dev')
s3 = aws_session.resource('s3')
```

2- To use resource `boto3.resource`:

```
import boto3
boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='dev')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
```

3- OR, Pass environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` to boto3.

```
import boto3
aws_session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SERVER_SECRET_KEY,
)
s3 = aws_session.resource('s3')
```

Comment: it's now `aws_session =  = boto3.Session(profile_name='dev')`. Not `aws_session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='dev'). [Ref](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html#shared-credentials-file)

Answer (score 8):

Just add profile to session configuration before client call.
`boto3.session.Session(profile_name='YOUR_PROFILE_NAME').client('cloudwatch')`

Comment: This worked (with decryption). Splitting this over two commands didn't.