# how to pull aws CloudTrail log using rest API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudtrail

I need help to fetch logs from AWS  CloudTrail via rest API.How can I get this rest API ?
I will use restAPI in my python code.

Comment: These are just files in S3 [according to the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-find-log-files.html).  Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205481/read-file-content-from-s3-bucket-with-boto3) for guidance on reading the file from S3.

Comment: You can get the CloudTrail files from S3 via the S3 REST API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html