# Download image from S3 bucket and store in a variable not in local (boto3)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to download an image from a bucket S3 and store in a variable, not in my local pc, how can I do it?

I'm using this code to store in local:

```
BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket' 
KEYFILE = 'myImage.jpg' 

try:
    s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEYFILE, 'myImageInLocal.jpg')          
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
        print("The object does not exist.")
    else:
        raise
```

Comment: [python - Read file content from S3 bucket with boto3 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205481/read-file-content-from-s3-bucket-with-boto3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download to [BytesIO](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BytesIO) variable with [download_fileobj](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_fileobj):

```
from io import BytesIO

BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket' 
KEYFILE = 'myImage.jpg' 

s3_file = BytesIO()

try:
    s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_fileobj('myImageInLocal.jpg', s3_file)          
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
        print("The object does not exist.")
    else:
        raise
```

Comment: But, in this case, I'm not specifying what is the KEYFILE to insert into s3_file

Comment: @Dharmansonofbeautifulb. Your keyfile is 'myImageInLocal.jpg'

Comment: Your code doesn't work, I get this error: "Fileobj must implement write"

Comment: @Dharmansonofbeautifulb It works now. The arguments were in the wrong order.

Comment: @Dharmansonofbeautifulb. No porblem. Glad it worked out:-)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try with BytesIO()

```
import io
image_data = io.BytesIO()
```

in your try block

```
s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEYFILE, image_data)
```

so image_data is the variable that should have the image in byte format.

Comment: Doesn't work because "Filename must be a string"