# Uploading file to S3 from local using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a requirement of uploading a file to AWS S3 bucket from local under organizational end point using python. Because i am a mainframe resource i dont have much idea on python but, when i tried to read some content got to know boto3 can help me. can someone please help me to start on this.

Comment: `boto3` is the best place to start.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read file content from S3 bucket with boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205481/read-file-content-from-s3-bucket-with-boto3)

Answer (score 0):

boto3 is a library you can use to interact with AWS by using Python.

You can lookup its official page: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html
You have not only the API documentation but also examples and user guides.

For your specific problem, you have the solution here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html