# botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound when code run on AWS elastic beanstalk, but locally it's OK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, boto3

I am trying to run a python application on an Elastic Beanstalk which need to have permissions for the SQS and Dynamo DB.

I have created a profile under ~/.aws/config file like this:

```
[profile yolo]
aws_access_key_id = some-key
aws_secret_access_key = some-secret
region = some-region
```

and also started the elastic beanstalk like:

```
eb init --profile yolo
```

but when I check the logs online it states:

```
botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (yolo) could not be found
```

How do I get the boto3 to know this profile on elastic beanstalk environment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You will also get this error if AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE environment variable is set, but no config file is present.

Comment: any solution ?!

Comment: My solution in that case was to create the ```~/.aws/config``` file.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your .aws/config file header to - `[yolo]` instead of `[profile yolo]`, and also separating the config and credentials to two files, as described in this link - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html
This should fix your problems.

Comment: the 'config' file must have the 'profile' prefix for each profile. However I'll try separating the credentials to the 'credentials' file and post here the results

Comment: Quoting the page I've linked to - "*Important*
The AWS credentials file uses a different naming format than the CLI config file for named profiles. Do not include the 'profile ' prefix when configuring a named profile in the AWS credentials file."

Comment: I was skeptic about your advice, but tried anyway - it didn't work. I moved the credentials to 'credentials' file under '[yolo]'. I called the profile under 'config' like '[yolo]' and '[profile yolo]', didn't solve.

It makes sense: both files are stored locally. Nothing moves them to AWS. Unlike the files that are under '.ebextensions' an 'elasticbeanstalk' for example, which are environment-specific, the 'credentials' and 'config' files are global for all environments.

If I had only one EC2 server, I would put both files there. But I can't do that when working on EB.

Comment: I just had the same problem and removing `profile` from `[profile foo]` in `~/.aws/credentials` did the trick for me.  I am now able to select the preferred set of credentials/profile using the methods indicated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378422/how-to-chose-an-aws-profile-when-using-boto3-to-connect-to-cloudfront).

Comment: In my case, I had the same error, and I needed to *add* `profile` to the name of my profile in ~/.aws/config -- changing it from `[foo]` to `[profile foo]`.