# Switching AWS Accounts in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

When using the AWS CLI it references the credentials and config files located in the ~/.aws directory. And you use the --profile flag to indicate which account you want. Such as:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --profile=company-lab
aws ec2 describe-instances --profile=company-nonprod
```

etc.

But I am new to scripting in python 3 and boto 3 and want to do the same thing there. How can I switch between AWS accounts using python?

Comment: Consider putting your credentials in enviroment variables, and then switching environments depending on your needs. This will keep sensitive data out of your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to choose an AWS profile when using boto3 to connect to CloudFront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378422/how-to-choose-an-aws-profile-when-using-boto3-to-connect-to-cloudfront)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `profile_nameˋ parameter when creating the session object.

```py
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='dev')
# Any clients created from this session will use credentials
# from the [dev] section of ~/.aws/credentials.
dev_s3_client = session.client('s3')
```

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html