# List resource for child account from master account using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-organizations

I am using python and boto3 to list resource that my organization has. I am listing the resources from my master account without a problem but I also need to list the resource from the child accounts as well. I can get the child account ID's but that's pretty much it.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You will need access to a set of credentials that belong to the child account.

From [Accessing and Administering the Member Accounts in Your Organization - AWS Organizations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_accounts_access.html#orgs_manage_accounts_access-cross-account-role):

> When you create a member account using the AWS Organizations console, AWS Organizations automatically **creates an IAM role** in the account. This role has full administrative permissions in the member account. The role is also configured to grant that access to the organization's master account.
>
> To use this role to access the member account, you must sign in as a user from the master account that has permissions to assume the role.

So, you can **assume the IAM Role in the child account**, which then provides a set of temporary credentials that can be used with `boto3` to make API calls to the child account.

```
import boto3

role_info = {
    'RoleArn': 'arn:aws:iam::<AWS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER>:role/<AWS_ROLE_NAME>',
    'RoleSessionName': '<SOME_SESSION_NAME>'
}

client = boto3.client('sts')
credentials = client.assume_role(**role_info)

session = boto3.session.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=credentials['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=credentials['Credentials']['SessionToken']
)
```

An **easier way** is to put the role in your `.aws/config` file as a new profile. Then, you can **specify a profile** when making function calls:

```
# In ~/.aws/credentials:
[master]
aws_access_key_id=foo
aws_secret_access_key=bar

# In ~/.aws/config
[profile child1]
role_arn=arn:aws:iam:...
source_profile=master
```

Use it like this:

```
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='dev')
s3 = session.client('s3')
```

See: [How to choose an AWS profile when using boto3 to connect to CloudFront](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33395432/174777)