# How to Write a script for daily uploading backups from local system to AWS S3 with specific AWS-Cli profile (Permission:Only Put to AWS S3)

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Script for daily Uploading files to S3 with specific aws-cli profile permission, after checking the correct user profile upload backup-files to s3

Comment: What is your local OS?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: the awscli `cp` command requires listobjects permission especially if you want to copy multiple files. `sync` command also needs listobject. If you cannot change permissions then it would be best to write your own logic using any of the AWS SDK languages.

Comment: I need sample(bash, python etc) for this how to write then i make my own script.

Comment: Ok python it is. I'll give you an example in python

Comment: Python, Node.js

Answer (score 1):

```
import boto3
import os

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')


def upload_to_s3(filepath, bucketname, prefix):
    for filename in os.listdir(filepath):
        s3.meta.client.upload_file(filepath + filename, bucketname, prefix + filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    local_file_path = ''
    bucket_name = ''
    prefix = ''
    upload_to_s3(local_file_path, bucket_name, prefix)
```

You can use something like this to upload all files inside your local backup directory to a bucket with a prefix of your choice.

Since you are on Ubuntu you can use cron job to schedule this script to run daily/weekdays. You can see a simple tutorial for this [here](https://medium.com/@gavinwiener/how-to-schedule-a-python-script-cron-job-dea6cbf69f4e).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378422/how-to-choose-an-aws-profile-when-using-boto3-to-connect-to-cloudfront/46041248
You can use this to create a session and specify user