# How to create recordset in Account2 from Account1

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-route53

I am trying to create a route53 recordset from Account1 in Account2.

From reading other posts and online search I am thinking of doing something like this:

```
from boto3 import Session

session = Session(aws_access_key_id=*****,aws_secret_access_key=****,region_name='us-east-1')
r53_client = session.client('route53')
r53_resource = session.resource('route53')
```

Want to know from someone experienced if this is the right way to do this? Or is there a better way to achieve above?

Here is updated code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    sts = boto3.client('sts')
    response = sts.assume_role(
        RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::***123:role/lambda',
        RoleSessionName='my-random-session-name',
        DurationSeconds= 900 # how many seconds these credentials will work
    )

    tempAccessKeyId = response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
    tempSecretAccessKey = response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey']
    tempSessionToken = response['Credentials']['SessionToken']

    client = boto3.client('route53', 
                  region_name = 'us-west-2',
                  aws_access_key_id=tempAccessKeyId,
                  aws_secret_access_key=tempSecretAccessKey,
                  aws_session_token=tempSessionToken)


    response = client.list_resource_record_sets(
    HostedZoneId='***',
    StartRecordName='test.example.com.',
    StartRecordType='A'
    )

    print(response)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that you are doing this from an AWS Lambda function, the most secure way to do it would be:

- In Account 1:

  - Create an IAM Role (`Role 1`) that will be used by the Lambda function
  - Assign permissions to the role that allows it to assume `Role-2`
  - Also assign any other permissions the Lambda function requires (you would normally add the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` managed policy to allow logging)
  - Assign `Role 1` to the Lambda function
- In Account 2:

  - Create an IAM Role (`Role 2`) with trust permissions that allows `Role 1` in Account 1 to assume it
  - Grant `Role 2` appropriate permissions to use Amazon Route 53

In your Lambda code, you would call `AssumeRole()` on `Role 2`. This will provide a set of temporary credentials that can be used to access Account 2 (as per your code, above).

See: [Switching to an IAM Role (AWS API) - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html)

Comment: I did as you suggested. Please see attached in question. But I am still getting error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the operation: User: arn:aws:sts::***:assumed-role/** is not authorized to access this resource

Comment: Which line is giving the error? It is probably because `Role 2` has not been granted the appropriate permissions for Route 53. What permissions are in that role?

Comment: It says - An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListResourceRecordSets operation: User: arn:aws:sts::***:assumed-role/ is not authorized to access this resource.  Role 1 lambda function has all route53 access. Role 2 has all route 53 access and account 1 added to it.

Comment: Do I need to attach route53 role I created to lambda function somehow if I am running it locally?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I figured it out. Will update code above that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To make an API call to an AWS account, you either need credentials from that AWS account (eg credentials associated with an IAM User), or you need the ability to *assume* an IAM Role in that account.

So, in your example, if the credentials being provided belong to Account2, then you will be able to make API calls to Account2 (if that IAM User has been granted the necessary Route 53 permissions).

If you are frequently moving between accounts, you can instead specify a `profile`, which retrieves a different set of credential from the credentials file.

See: [python - How to choose an AWS profile when using boto3 to connect to CloudFront - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33395432/174777)

Comment: I am trying to do this through a lambda so I dont think profile will work. So you suggest assume role is best way to go?