# Passing AWS role to the application that uses default boto3 configs

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, great-expectations

I have an aws setup that requires me to assume role and get corresponding credentials in order to write to s3. For example, to write with `aws cli`, I need to use `--profile readwrite` flag. If I write code myself with boot, I'd assume role via `sts`, get credentials, and create new session.

However, there is a bunch of applications and packages relying on boto3's configuration, e.g. internal code runs like this:

```py
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
result_s3 = s3.Object(bucket, s3_object_key)
result_s3.put(
                Body=value.encode(content_encoding),
                ContentEncoding=content_encoding,
                ContentType=content_type,
        )
```

From documentation, boto3 can be set to use default profile using (among others) `AWS_PROFILE` env variable, and it clearly "works" in terms that `boto3.Session().profile_name` does match the variable - but the applications still won't write to s3.

What would be the cleanest/correct way to set them properly? I tried to pull credentials from sts, and write them as AWS_SECRET_TOKEN etc, but that didn't work for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct answer to my question is one shared by Nathan Williams in the comment.

In my specific case, given that I had to initiate code from python, and was a bit worried about setting AWS settings that might spill into other operations, I used
the fact that boto3 has `DEFAULT_SESSION` singleton, used each time, and just overwrote this with a session that assumed the proper role:

```
hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id=aws_conn_id)  
boto3.DEFAULT_SESSION = hook.get_session()
```

(here, S3Hook is airflow's s3 handling object). After that (in the same runtime) everything worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the answer here:
[How to choose an AWS profile when using boto3 to connect to CloudFront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378422/how-to-choose-an-aws-profile-when-using-boto3-to-connect-to-cloudfront)

You can get boto3 to use the other profile like so:

```
rw = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='readwrite')
s3 = rw.resource('s3')
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I am afraid I cannot do that because boto3 is used within the application I use (great expectations) which I ran via terminal, and I hope I won’t need to maintain custom copy

Comment: Maybe something like this can help:
https://ripon-banik.medium.com/aws-assume-role-script-4e7d3b548f20
Look at example 1, put that in a bash script and source it before you call your application
(You will need JQ installed, and you can ignore the last 3 lines of the script if you only need it for this one use case)