# How do I loop around multiple accounts' aws credentials which are to be passed to a python script from a .env file?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have 3 aws accounts and I need to list ec2 instances in all of those accounts using a python script.
Here, I need to pass the aws access key id and aws secret access key in the `.env` file.

How do I set it up?

Comment: You are missing a little of context.
How is presented your .env file? Are the access_key_id and secret_access_key the same for the 3 accounts and then you need to switch roles, or directly to the target account?

Comment: Do you mean `~/.aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config`, which are the standard files for AWS credentials, rather than `.env`?

Comment: No, the access key id and secret access key are different for all 3 accounts.

Comment: @jarmod no i meant the .env file.

Comment: What is the .env file? The AWS Python SDK doesn't use .env files afaik. Which AWS SDK do you use this .env file with? BTW if using the regular AWS config files (see above), you [supply a profile name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378422/how-to-choose-an-aws-profile-when-using-boto3-to-connect-to-cloudfront) when creating a session.

Comment: I used the boto3 SDK. For a single account the env file i created was: aws_account="abc"
aws_access_key_id="xyz"
aws_secret_access_key="jkl"
aws_session_token="mno"

Comment: How do you present this .env file and your preferred profile, assuming it can contain multiple profiles, to the boto3 SDK?

Comment: import boto3    
from dotenv import load_dotenv    
import os    
load_dotenv()    
  
aws_account=os.getenv("aws_account")  
aws_access_key_id=os.getenv("aws_access_key_id")  
aws_secret_access_key=os.getenv("aws_secret_access_key")  
aws_session_token=os.getenv("aws_session_token")

Comment: I recommend you use the [standard config files](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html) with AWS SDKs. They also support multiple profiles. The dotenv files appear to be simple key/value pairs akin to bash environment settings.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to pass the list of your profile names in your code

```
import boto3
available_profiles = [
    'your-profile-name'
]
available_regions = [
    'us-east-1',
    'eu-west-1'
]
# for each account, each region, create a session and then ec2 client. 
# You could also go with creation of a session in account and then only client in each region
for profile in available_profiles:
    for region in available_regions:
        aws_session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=profile, region_name=region)
        ec2_client = aws_session.client(service_name='ec2', region_name=region)
        paginator = ec2_client.get_paginator('describe_instances')
        ec2_instances = paginator.paginate()
        all_instances = list()

        for response in ec2_instances:
            for reservation in response.get('Reservations', list()):
                for instance in reservation.get('Instances', list()):
                    instance['account_id'] = reservation['OwnerId']
                    all_instances.append(instance)
```