# How to upload image to aws s3 folder using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

> upload = s3.upload_file('image.png','bucket name','folder_in_s3'+image2.png')

I am trying to upload a file to s3 bucket folder. I can't get the path for a folder to upload.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Helpful may be ["how to ask good questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Users here are way more ready to help if you provide [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with some input and the desired output.

Comment: It is better if you could give a more detailed description and also check if this solves your issue.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378763/how-to-save-s3-object-to-a-file-using-boto3

Comment: Does the above code work? What error message or problem are you having? This code seems to have the wrong number of quotes: `'folder_in_s3'+image2.png'`