# How to upload url to s3 bucket using StringIO and put_object method with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, boto, stringio

I need to upload URLs to an s3 bucket and am using boto3. I thought I had a solution with this question: [How to save S3 object to a file using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378763/how-to-save-s3-object-to-a-file-using-boto3) but when I go to download the files, I'm still getting errors. The goal is for them to download as audio files, not URLs. My code:

```
    for row in list_reader:
        media_id = row['mediaId']
        external_id = row['externalId']
        with open('10-17_res1.csv', 'a') as results_file:
            file_is_empty = os.stat('10-17_res1.csv').st_size == 0
            results_writer = csv.writer(
            results_file, delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"'
            )
            if file_is_empty:
                results_writer.writerow(['fileURL','key', 'mediaId','externalId'])

            key = 'corpora/' + external_id + '/' + external_id + '.flac'
            bucketname = 'my_bucket'

            media_stream = media.get_item(media_id)
            stream_url = media_stream['streams'][0]['streamLocation']


            fake_handle = StringIO(stream_url)
            s3c.put_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=key, Body=fake_handle.read())
```

My question is, what do I need to change so that the file is saved in s3 as an audio file, not a URL?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using the smart_open module:

```
        with smart_open.open(stream_url, 'rb',buffering=0) as f:
            s3.put_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=key, Body=f.read())
```

Note that it won't work without the 'buffering=0' parameter.